# How to set default paramType to query. current is body

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

If I do not set paramType = "query", password is body. How to change?

```
@ApiOperation("登录")
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "account", value = "用户名或手机号码", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "password", value = "密码")
})
@RequestMapping
public JR login(String account, String password) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(account) || StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        return JR.fail(2, "请填写完整信息");
    }
    User user = userRepository.findByAccountOrPhone(account, account);
    if (user != null && StringUtils.md5(password).equals(user.getPassword())) {
        ApiUtils.loginInfo(user, userRepository, true);
        return JR.success(user);
    }
    return JR.fail(1, "账号或密码错误");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting it in the `swagger` annotation you should specify query params in your `method` using `@RequestParam` like the following:

```
@ApiOperation("登录")
@RequestMapping
public JR login(@RequestParam("account")  String account, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(account) || StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        return JR.fail(2, "请填写完整信息");
    }
    User user = userRepository.findByAccountOrPhone(account, account);
    if (user != null && StringUtils.md5(password).equals(user.getPassword())) {
        ApiUtils.loginInfo(user, userRepository, true);
        return JR.success(user);
    }
    return JR.fail(1, "账号或密码错误");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need ApiImplicitParam.value, is there a way to write less code but show ApiImplicitParam.value and paramType="query"?

Comment: you should use `@ApiModelProperty(value = "xxx"...)` on the parameter itself.